# What does “in experimental challenges” mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Would you tell me what "in experimental challenges" means in this sentence?

> In experimental challenges, immunity is serotype specific.
> <sub>Source: [Oxford Textbook of Medicine: Infection](http://books.google.com/books?id=qkLibW2ZikYC&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=%22In+experimental+challenges,+immunity+is+serotype+specific.%22)</sub>

Comment: It's a challenge in an experimental environment. Without more context, it will be hard to figure out what more it means. It sounds like a piece of specialized writing, where the reader is supposed to be familiar with the vocabulary already... I mean, if _serotype_ is part of your working lexicon, you should probably know how _experiments_ are performed.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! This question is fine, but in the future you may find that you get better results if you can write a little bit about the context in which you encountered the issue, as well as your thoughts on the matter. For example, you might include something like “I could understand if it just said ‘in experiments’ but the word ‘challenge’ throws me off.” I’ve had to make some assumptions as to the source of the passage and the nature of your confusion. Please re-edit your question if you wish to provide more detail about either.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence employs a specialized use of the word “challenge”. I found the following definitions by typing “define challenge medical” into Google. Thefreedictionary.com has a medical dictionary section (where I found these), and it might work best in the future to keep that section of that website handy so you can quickly look up medical terms when you are confused by a particular passage. If you plan to study or practice medicine extensively, you may wish to invest in your own copy of a medical dictionary.

> **challenge** /chal·lenge/ (chal´enj)
>
> 1. to administer a substance to monitor for the normal physiological response.
> 2. in immunology, to administer an antigen to monitor the response in a sensitized person.
>
> <sub>Source: Definition of “challenge” in Dorland's Medical Dictionary for Health Consumers, via [thefreedictionary.com](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/challenge)</sub>

> **challenge**
>
> 1. a method of testing the sensitivity of an individual to a hormone, allergen, or other substance by administering a sample. A small amount may be injected to determine whether the immune system will react by producing appropriate antibodies.
>
> <sub>Source: Definition of “challenge” in Mosby's Medical Dictionary, via [thefreedictionary.com](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/challenge)</sub>

“Experimental challenge” as a term is somewhat redundant, given the definitions above, but it does help indicate the special nature of the second word. [Later in the textbook, you will encounter the term “challenge” by itself](http://books.google.com/books?id=qkLibW2ZikYC&dq=challenge&q=challenge#v=snippet&q=challenge&f=false) and you will need to decide whether it is used in the sense of an experiment performed or refers to an encountered difficulty.

“**In** experimental challenge” defines a scope. The author is limiting the statement to a report of results from trials in labs rather than suggesting that what follows is a universal truth or is the result of observation of natural occurrence. This manner of writing is common in scientific texts, and functions as a way of being responsible for the source of data and resultant conclusions.